# Getting the data From Soap response convertion into java object?

Tags: xml, xpath

I Have one soap service which gives me the response in the following format

`<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
    <ns2:getUsersResponse xmlns:ns2="http://soap.com/">
    <return>
    <email>email</email>
    <id>uid</id>
    <lastName>last_name</lastName>
    <userName>first_name</userName>
    </return>
    <return>
    <email>aladdin.scott@testingatgsl.com</email>
    <id>aladdin.scott@testingatgsl.com</id>
    <lastName>Scott</lastName>
    <userName>Aladdin</userName>
    </return>
    <return>
    <email>alice.wonderland@testingatgsl.com</email>
    <id>alice.wonderland@testingatgsl.com</id>
    <lastName>Wonderland</lastName>
    <userName>Alice</userName>
    </return>
    </ns2:getUsersResponse>
    </S:Body>
    </S:Envelope>`

I want convert this into java objects of class given below.

`class User  {
    String uid ;
    String email;
    String fisrtName;
    String lastName;
    }`

By using Xpath , I am not getting the right way to do  ??

Comment: "XPath" has little or nothing to do with the problem.  XPath can give you syntax for finding a "return" element ... but you can just as easily do the same without XPath.  The key thing is *you should start with the WSDL*.  The WSDL defines a "contract" for the service. If the service ever changes, the WSDL should change, too.  The simplest - and most robust - solution is to 1) use wsgen to read the WSDL, and 2) use the standard JAX-WS APIs to implement your  code.  IMHO...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: Why don't you use a Web Service framework like Axis2 or CXF?

Or simply use "wsgen" and JAX-WS annotations?

Here are a few tutorials:

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example-document-style/

http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-ws-tutorials/

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXWS3.html

NOTE:

You'll want to start by running wsgen (or equivalent) on your web service's WSDL.  You probably *don't* want to manually hand-code your Java by reverse-engineering specific SOAP responses.

The tutorials above should make this clearer...

'Hope that helps!

Comment: that will be specific  to one soap response  but if the  response changes  then ??  I want make it generic for diff soap responses.. By using Xpath I can do it  ?